# App which use gradle get error "Native method not found"

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, gradle

I use gradle to generate apks. After I install it,the released version got the error:    `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.fss.e.b.a:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;`

But the debug one looks good.The build.gradle which I wrote is below:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':fss:libs:actionbarsherlock')
    compile project(':fss:libs:library')
    compile project(':library')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"
    signingConfigs {
        myConfig{

        }
    }


    buildTypes{

        release {
            signingConfig  signingConfigs.myConfig
        }


    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
tasks.withType(Compile) {  
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"  
}  
task copyNativeLibs(type: Copy) {
  from fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.so' )
    into  'build/native-libs'
}

tasks.withType(Compile) { compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn copyNativeLibs }

clean.dependsOn 'cleanCopyNativeLibs'

tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.jniDir new File('build/native-libs')
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm: you explicitly register `com.fss.e.b.a` from JNI, or have a `Java_com_fss_e_b_a` method declared in a native library?  I ask because that looks like Proguard obfuscation.

Comment: @fadden Yes,that's proguard obfuscation.So how to let the it link the native method which use obfuscation?

Answer (score 0):

Add these to keep native methods.The error will be solved.

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```